# Piping smbpasswd via Java

Tags: java, ubuntu, automation, samba

I tried to piping password to smbpassword via Java application, here how I pipe via terminal:

```
(echo newPassword; echo confirmPassword) | smbpasswd -a -s client1
```

and the output show the command is nicely done:

```
Added user client1
```

However, I cannot accomplish this via Java application, here the codes that I use:

```
public void run(String command, String[] prompt) {
    try {
        String[] args = new String[] {"/bin/bash","-c","echo " + rootPassword + "| sudo -S " + command};
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();

        if (prompt != null && prompt.length > 0) {
            for (int i = 0; i < prompt.length; i++) {
                proc.getOutputStream().write((prompt[i] + "\r\n").getBytes());
                proc.getOutputStream().flush();
            }
        }

        proc.waitFor();

        String output = "";
        String line;
        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            System.out.println(line);
            output += line + "\n";
        }
        System.out.println(output);
        input.close();
    }
    catch (Exception ex) {
        System.out.println(null, ex.getMessage());
    }
}
```

and I tried to use OutputStream it like:

```
String[] pipe = { password, password };
run("smbpasswd -s -a " + username, pipe);
```

or pipe it like:

```
run("(echo " + password + "; echo " + password + ") | smbpasswd -s -a " + username, null);
```

but both doesn't work and I got no output and the user seems not created after I check via `pdbedit -L`. However, I able to execute another command with pipe such as `echo username:password | chpasswd` via that function.

Any idea?
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

The main conceptual problem is that shell code such as you are trying to run:

> ```
> (echo newPassword; echo confirmPassword) | smbpasswd -a -s client1
> ```

is not a "command" in the sense that `sudo` requires.  In fact, it's not a "command" even in shell terminology; rather, it's a *pipeline*, consisting of a compound command and a simple command.  `sudo` expects you to provide a simple command.

But that's actually a bit of an aside.  Your problem isn't really specific to `sudo`; rather, it's a shell problem.  In the failure case, your `run()` method invokes `bash` to execute the following shell code:

```
echo rootPassword | sudo -S (echo newPassword; echo confirmPassword) | smbpasswd -a -s client1
```

That's problematic for at least two reasons:

1. A subshell invocation cannot appear in a simple command's (i.e. `sudo`'s) argument list like that.  You could put a command substitution there (`$(echo ...)`), but that will not serve your purpose because the internal line break will not then be preserved.
2. Even if you solved (1), your second pipe is at the wrong level: it would pipe the output of `sudo` into `smbpasswd`.  That's fine data-wise, but it leaves `smbpasswd` running without privilege -- the `sudo` does not apply to it.

You could probably solve the problem by instructing `sudo` to run the code via a shell.  You could do that by embedding the ultimate command inside an inner `bash -c` command<strike>, but it would probably be easier to use `sudo`'s `-s` option (but beware that `-s` can choose a different shell than `bash` if you let it do)</strike>.  Something along those lines is probably the most general solution if you want to encode the whole operation in a single String in your Java source:

```
    String[] args = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c",
            "echo " + rootPassword + " | sudo -S -s '" + command + "'" };
```

```
    String[] args = new String[] { "/bin/bash", "-c",
            "echo " + rootPassword + " | sudo -S bash -c '" + command + "'" };
```

Much of your problem, however, arises from your reliance on `echo` to feed data to your commands.  You should consider instead using your `Process`'s `OutputStream` to feed data to it from your Java program.  That does not lend itself to quite as simple a Java-side API, but I think you're fooling yourself a bit about how simple your API really is.  It has hidden gotchas, as you discovered, and even the revision I offered above still has at least one: it will likely break if the command submitted to it contains a single-quote character (`'`).

### Update:

Here's one way to feed the process the needed data via its `OutputStream`:

```
    public void run2(String command, String commandInput)
            throws IOException, InterruptedException {
        String[] args = new String[] { "sudo", "-S", "bash", "-c", command };
        Process proc = new ProcessBuilder(args).start();
        Writer toProc = new OutputStreamWriter(proc.getOutputStream());

        toProc.write(rootPassword, 0, rootPassword.length());
        toProc.write('\n');
        toProc.write(commandInput, 0, commandInput.length());
        toProc.close();
        proc.waitFor();

        BufferedReader input = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(proc.getInputStream()));
        StringBuilder output = new StringBuilder();
        String line;

        while ((line = input.readLine()) != null) {
            output.append(line).append('\n');
        }
        System.out.println("Command output:");
        System.out.println(output.toString());
        input.close();
    }
```

You might use that from within its class as

```
run2("smbpasswd -a -s client1", "newPassword\nnewPassword");
```

Note in particular that the `Process`'s output stream must, in general, be *closed* after you've written everything you intend to write to it.  Some commands you could run will not exit if you do not do so.

**Note also**

For the general case, you must read every `Process`'s input stream and error stream (or just the former if you combine them), *in parallel* with the process itself.  If you have not combined the streams then you must read them in parallel with each other.  If you are writing to the process's output stream then that, too, must be in parallel.  If you do not arrange to handle each stream via its own thread then it is possible for the process to get stuck.

On the other hand, you *don't* need a separate thread to run the `Process` itself in -- after all, it represents an entire separate process.  Just defer waiting for it until you have closed its output stream and read the end of its input and error streams.

Comment: Thanks for your answer and explanation!
I tried the array of arguments that u gave, but the pipeline isn't working and the InputStream doesn't feed me the output..

about OutputStream, I updated my question, perhaps you can give me an correct example of code to do it?

Comment: @lumine, the `-s` option was a bad choice, sorry, though the general idea was sound.  I have updated that part of my answer.  I have also provided an example of how you might simplify things by feeding data directly from Java to the external process.  This is still not a general-purpose solution (see my added comments on parallelism), but it should serve cases were little output is produced.